# Diffeomorphisms of circle extends to diffeomorphisms of disk

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, heat-equation

Any diffeomorphism of a circle can be extended to a diffeomorphism of a circle. I was trying to do it by using the [Radó–Kneser–Choquet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rad%C3%B3%E2%80%93Kneser%E2%80%93Choquet_theorem) as provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513243/extending-diffeomorphism-to-disk). I did the proof which is given in the Duren's book *Harmonic mappings in the plane*. But, he only proves about the homeomorphism. How to prove the diffeomorphism. Any help!

Comment: How about the proof in the Wikipedia article? How about Neal's proof in the other thread? I haven't checked either one personally, but both claim to demonstrate diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @PaulSinclair First of all Neal's proof is fine but that is not by Poisson Kernel. I am proving that by Poisson kernel. In Wikipedia, it is proved about the homeomorphic extension, not the diffeomorphic extension.

Comment: The Wikipedia article proves the map is a local diffeomorphism, then proves it is a homeomorphism. A homeomorphism that is a local diffeomorphism is a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, it is there. But it is difficult for me to understand. Anyway, I will again try it. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSinclair,  if you see the wiki proof,  he has mentioned that jacobian is nonzero will imply the local diffeomorphism.  But that is what I am not understaning why?  Asbper as I know,  it will prove local homeomorphism.

Comment: For the jacobian to even exist, the map has to be differentiable, and saying that the jacobian is non-zero means that the derivative matrix is invertible. By the inverse mapping theorem, the map is locally invertible, and further, the inverse map is differentiable, with the inverse of the derivative matrix of the original being the derivative matrix of the inverse. In 1D, this is because a tangent line this is not vertical or horizontal is also neither vertical nor horizontal after you exchange $x$ and $y$ (reflect the graph through the line $y = x$).

Comment: Yeah, true but this diffeomorphism is locally and hence the diffeomorphism will be in the interior. Why the derivative will match on the boundary. As I have checked the continuity at the boundary and it satisfies with the given diffeomorphism, but not sure with the derivatives.

Comment: Note the opening sentence of the Wikipedia article: "In mathematics, the Radó–Kneser–Choquet theorem, named after Tibor Radó, Hellmuth Kneser and Gustave Choquet, states that the Poisson integral of a homeomorphism of the unit circle is a harmonic diffeomorphism of the **open** unit disk." There is no boundary.